# Bash: How to break a string into array elements according to a delimiter

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, unix

I've read and tried different approaches (e.g IFS, AWK, SED) on how to tokenize this kind of string:

```
data|date|token1|token2|process_job.sh Y
```

I want to delimit it using **'|'** and access the tokenized string like this:

- arr[0] expected value is data
- arr[1] expected value is date
- arr[2] expected value is token1
- arr[3] expected value is token2
- arr[4] expected value is process_job.sh Y

**Problem:**

When I tried to access the arr[4] I always get *process_job.sh* only not the *process_job.sh Y*

Any ideas for me guys? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read`:

```
# original string
s='data|date|token1|token2|process_job.sh Y'

# read into an array using IFS=|
IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$s"

# check array values
declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="data" [1]="date" [2]="token1" [3]="token2" [4]="process_job.sh Y")'
```

Comment: hello @Anubhava I edited my question. Is your answer changing the values of every index in the array? Sorry I'm new in shell scripting. Just want to clarify.

Comment: I didn't get your question. My script is not changing any value, it is using tokenized string to populate an array. `declare -p arr` is used to **print** the array values.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
s="data|date|token1|token2|process_job.sh Y"
IFS="|" arr=($s)
echo "${arr[0]}"
```

Output:

```
data
```

Comment: This will leave `IFS` set to `|` in the sell.

Comment: yes, when I used the `IFS` I stored the previous value and change it back to its original. Anyway, thanks to both of you guys :)

Comment: Yes, same thing I had it my comments below my answer.